# Displaying images on a canvas using ctx.drawImage()?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've trawled the web looking for a solution to my problem. Right now I'm trying to display an image within a canvas, yet no matter what I do, the image simply won't display. I've made sure that the path is correct and the .png file is in the right place.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="focusArea" onmousemove="updateLocation()">
  <canvas id="ctx" width="1000" height="1000" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
   var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
   ctx.font = '30px Arial';

   var socket = io();

   function updateLocation() {
     socket.emit('mouse', { inputID: 'mouse', xloc: event.clientX, yloc: event.clientY, state: true});
   }

   socket.on('newPositions', function(data) {
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
     ctx.fillText(data[i].number, data[i].x, data[i].y);

     var image = new Image();
     image.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    };
     image.src = "player.png";
   });
</script>
```

Would really appreciate if someone could suggest a fix. Thanks!

Comment: where is your player.png? do you see any console errors? Is your socket connect to some server? Is your code going into the routine which draws image?

Comment: look up how to get "setTimeout in for loop" working, you've got the same issue with the async onload.

Comment: @spooky My socket is connecting to a local server. I'm trying to make a simple Javascript game with multiplayer right now. My "player.png" file is in the same folder as this file.

Comment: @dandavis Don't think it is to do with the loop, since I've tried the code in different divs, etc :/

Comment: try `image.onload = function (e){ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);};`

Comment: @dandavis No luck :(

Comment: Sample working code here: https://jsfiddle.net/qL6wx071/ now you can hook-up your socket code.

Comment: Add `image.onerror = function(){alert("Image load error");}` to ensure that the cause is not a load error. Everything else looks good so must be a error due to bad URL or bad image

Comment: @spooky Thanks - it was something to do with a bad image after all ;) - really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Blindman67 Yeah - you're right :D it was a bad image I believe.

Comment: @dandavis You could do `image.onload = function(){ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);}` as well.

Comment: @skua glad it worked out.

Comment: @spooky Having an issue trying to make the image move to the mouse now. Whilst using this code: ctx.drawImage(e.target, data[i].x, data[i].y); nothing displays :/

Comment: @spooky But if the parameters are 0 then the image does display?

Comment: @Skua sounds like coordinates are our of canvas?

Comment: @spooky Basically I'm trying to make the image move to the coordinates of the cursor.

Comment: @Skua Works well for me... check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/qL6wx071/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the problem was to do with the image encoding :)